# Output of Graph Convolution in deepchem

Tags: deep-learning, rdkit

I am using  [Deepchem](https://deepchem.io/) to create features for the my  [GraphConvolution](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5028207/) model as follows.

```
import deepchem as dc
from rdkit import Chem
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole

smile = 'O=C(C1=CC=C(C=C1)C(O)=O)O'
molecules = []
molecules.append(Chem.MolFromSmiles(smile))
featurizer = dc.feat.graph_features.ConvMolFeaturizer()
mol_object = featurizer.featurize(mols=molecules)
```

Now I want to know the output `mol_object`. I know that `dc.feat.graph_features.ConvMolFeaturizer()` returns an array object. But it actually does to the input.

So the `featurizer.featurize(mols=molecules)` takes `molecules`as input.
The `molecules[0]` will print the following graph.

[image: Ml]

As `molecules` is a list which contains only one element at index 0 which is `molecules[0]`. That means that `mols` in `dc.feat.graph_features.ConvMolFeaturizer()` takes this image as input and outputs `mol_object`.

What is this `mol_object` output and how can I see it? Is shows that it is an array but I can not see the content of this array?

```
print(np.shape(mol_object))
(1,)
print(type(mol_object))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(mol_object)
[<deepchem.feat.mol_graphs.ConvMol object at 0x7f96a68c6e48>]
```

How do I inspect or see `[<deepchem.feat.mol_graphs.ConvMol object at 0x7f96a68c6e48>]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not look at the [source code](https://github.com/deepchem/deepchem/blob/master/deepchem/feat/mol_graphs.py#L46) for the ConvMol object?

The output of the featurizer returns an array of ConvMol objects (one for each rdkit molecule input) i.e. deepchem.feat.mol_graphs.ConvMol, what you actually want to inspect is the first element of the array, mol_object[0].

Looking at the source code you can then understand what information about the molecule is contained such as the atom features which can be accessed ConvMol.atom_features, or in your case mol_object[0].atom_features