# Deepchem disk data to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, rdkit

I am using  [Deepchem](https://deepchem.io/) wrapper for [GraphConvolution](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5028207/) model as follows. I have my smiles data in `.csv` which consists of 5 molecules with their smiles representation and their respective activities. The data can be accessed from [here](https://github.com/Abdulk084/stackoverflow/blob/master/train_smiles_data.csv) directly.

**Importing the libraries:**

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import deepchem as dc
from deepchem.models.tensorgraph.models.graph_models import GraphConvModel
```

**Loading the data and featurizing it in a way so that it is suitable for Graph-convolution.**

```
graph_featurizer = dc.feat.graph_features.ConvMolFeaturizer()
loader_train = dc.data.data_loader.CSVLoader( tasks=['Activity'], smiles_field="smiles",featurizer=graph_featurizer)
dataset_train = loader_train.featurize( './train_smiles_data.csv')
```

**Analyzing the loaded and featurized data  (My Try)**

```
dataset_train.X

array([<deepchem.feat.mol_graphs.ConvMol object at 0x7f8bfc3ad748>,
       <deepchem.feat.mol_graphs.ConvMol object at 0x7f8bfc367828>,
       <deepchem.feat.mol_graphs.ConvMol object at 0x7f8bfc367208>,
       <deepchem.feat.mol_graphs.ConvMol object at 0x7f8bfc369c50>],
      dtype=object)


dataset_train.y

array([[2.71],
       [4.41],
       [3.77],
       [4.2 ]])

for x, y, w, id in dataset_train.itersamples():
    print(x, y, w, id)

<deepchem.feat.mol_graphs.ConvMol object at 0x7f8bfc3ad6a0> [2.71] [1.] CC1=C(O)C=CC=C1
<deepchem.feat.mol_graphs.ConvMol object at 0x7f8bfc30f518> [4.41] [1.] [O-][N+](=O)C1=CC=C(Br)S1
<deepchem.feat.mol_graphs.ConvMol object at 0x7f8bfc30f748> [3.77] [1.] CCC/C=C/C=O
<deepchem.feat.mol_graphs.ConvMol object at 0x7f8bfc30f940> [4.2] [1.] CCCCCC1=CC=CS1
```

**What I want?**

As it seems from the above code, `dataset_train.X` gives a `diskobject` like `<deepchem.feat.mol_graphs.ConvMol object at 0x7f8bfc3ad6a0>` and not a `numpy array` like `dataset_train.y`.

How do I know what type of data is stored in `dataset_train.X`? How can I see the data stored in `dataset_train.X`? Or in another words, how can I convert the `dataset_train.X` into such a format where I can inspect the data in it?

I believe there should be some way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280528/output-of-graph-convolution-in-deepchem/58283700#58283700) dataset_train.X is an array of ConvMol objects. These ConvMol objects are a container for the features of each of your input molecules. The features are not represented like they are for your targets 'train_dataset.y' as they are more complex graph features. look at the [source code](https://github.com/deepchem/deepchem/blob/master/deepchem/feat/mol_graphs.py#L46) for the ConvMol object again and look at the [source code](https://github.com/deepchem/deepchem/blob/master/deepchem/feat/graph_features.py#L275) for the ConvMolFeaturizer. You can then determine how you want to interpret these features:

```
# Inspect features for molecule 0
conv_feature = dataset_train.X[0]
# Print the atom features
print(conv_feature.get_atom_features())
# Print the adjacency list
print(conv_feature.get_adjancency_list())
```